# Tablayout Drop Shadow Disappears after I click another tab on Android Pre-lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml, android-tablayout

I am trying to create a drop shadow after the tablayout but it disappears right after I click another tab or I scrolled down the view pager beneath it. Here's what happens after I scroll it down.

The drop shadow appear after the first loading :

[image: drop shadow appear]

After I scrolled down, The drop shadow disappear :

[image: drop shadow disappear]

After I click another tab, the drop shadow disappears as well :

[image: drop shadow disappear after i clicked another tab]

But after I scrolled up again and clicked back to its first destination, the shadow appears again!

[image: drop shadow appears again!]

I already scoured over SO but I can seem to find an answer. Hope you guys can help me.

My code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_lane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/lighter_purple_99"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_lane_settings"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icn_settings" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white_100"
        android:background="@color/lighter_purple_99"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:elevation="4dp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow_below_tabs2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs2"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs2"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        tools:context="TabActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The drawable/shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="#ff000000"
        android:angle="90">
    </gradient>
</shape>
```

I have already tried :

-- AppBarLayout but it there's a background on drop shadow so it looks ugly.

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Just put the shadow view under the viewpager. This way, the shadow will be the last one to be displayed and placed on top of the viewpager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_lane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/lighter_purple_99"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_lane_settings"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icn_settings" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white_100"
        android:background="@color/lighter_purple_99"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:elevation="4dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs2"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        tools:context="com.dojomadness.lolsumo.activities.LaneActivity" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs2"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```